# Unsuccesful conversion of integer into Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I want to apply a filter of redundant signals in my algorithm where 'to_keep' will be a container for masking of signals, setting first value to 'True'.
'last_kept_date' will be temporary variable holding the last signal date to include in final list.
All data are pandas dataframe with date as indices (typical financial data)

```
signals = data.loc[(data['cc50'] == 0) & (data['cc50'].shift(1) >= 5)]

signals.loc[:, 'to_keep'] = False
signals.loc[0, 'to_keep'] = True

last_kept_date =  signals.index[0]

for i in signals.index:
    if (i - last_kept_date).days > 365 * 15 /12:
        last_kept_date = i
        signals.loc[i, 'to_keep'] = True
        continue
```

running the code raises error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'Timestamp'
```

hence I tried to convert to datestamp so that the same type of data will be substracted by changing:

last_kept_date =  signals.index[0]

into:

last_kept_date =  pd.to_datestamp(signals.index[0])

but still:

```
module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_datestamp'
```

What else can I do so that I will be able to subtract these time indices?

Comment: This is a bit of a vague question without toy data. It would be helpful to know where the error occurred in your code, but I assume it's in `i - last_kept_date`. Since it seems that `i` is an int, it could be an issue with setting up looping over an index. Also, pandas doesn't have a to_datestamp function as evidenced by the error, but it does have a [`DataFrame.to_timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html). I'm not sure if it's helps you there.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example